# c# FormatException when using Convert.toint32() on regex match then applying to numericupdown

Tags: c#, regex, converters, numericupdown, formatexception

ill get right to the point.  I am using regex to get a match from a settings file.  It simply grabs the default values.  I take the match, have it print the String match.  then I use Convert.toInt32(match) and put that into an int tempval.  Here is the code.

```
string[] settings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Settings.txt");
MatchCollection settingsmatch;
Regex expression = new Regex(@"first number: (\d+)");
settingsmatch = expression.Matches(settings[0]);
MessageBox.Show(settingsmatch[0].Value);
int tempval = Convert.ToInt32("+" + settingsmatch[0].Value.Trim());   //here is the runtime error
numericUpDown1.Value = tempval;
```

here is the settings text file:

```
first number: 35
second number: 4
default test file: DefaultTest.txt
```

I know that the problem is the Convert because I commented out the numericupdown line and still got the error in runtime.

It is a Formatexeption error.  I dont get it.  I though that my match is a string so Convert should take it.  Furthermore the messagebox.show is showing me a number.  The number 35 to be exact.  What else could cause this?

Comment: What *exactly* is the message box displaying? `35`, or `first number: 35`?

Comment: What happens if you leave the `"+"` out of the `Convert.ToInt32()` call? Doesn't seem like it serves a purpose.

Comment: Michael:  it is displaying "35".  It was showing "first number: 35" at first but I fixed that.

Tieson:  I was doing it without the "+" at first as well, I put it in because the MSDN page for FormatException said that I might be missing a sign.  I thought it might help, it didnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is converting the value of entire match to `Integer`. You need to convert the value of first group capture.

```
// convert the value of first group instead of entire match
//    settingsmatch[0].Value is "first number: 35"
//    settingsmatch[0].Groups[1].Value is "35"
int tempval = Convert.ToInt32("+" + settingsmatch[0].Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: that was it. I will mark yours as the answer. Thank you.  I get matches, but I dont get the groups. I will look more into groups.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The first match will be `first number: 35`.  In order to get the matched number, use the `Match.Groups` property.

```
settingsmatch = expression.Matches(settings[0]);
MessageBox.Show(settingsmatch[0].Groups[1].Value);
int tempval = Convert.ToInt32(settingsmatch[0].Groups[1].Value); // .Trim() is not needed because you are matching digits only
```